# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( in Azure Function when referencing npm package

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, webhint

I'm trying to create a JavaScript-based Azure Function that calls the webhint API. I have successfully created the function app, a function, initialized a package and installed the hint npm package. In my function code I'm doing the following:

```js
var hint = require('hint');

module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var webhint = hint.Analyzer.create({}, {});
    var result = webhint.analyze('https://google.com', {});
    context.done();
};
```

When running the function app I see the following error in the console:

```
mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.WebHintFunction. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. C:\projects\webhint-function-app\WebhintFunction\WebHintFunction\node_modules\hint\dist\src\lib\engine.js:133
                    immediateId = setImmediate(async () => {
                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\webhint-function-app\WebhintFunction\WebHintFunction\node_modules\hint\dist\src\lib\index.js:6:10).
```

The error is coming from within hint but I'm thinking that something is wrong with either my function version, node version or javascript version. I have tried adding the following to the `local.settings.json` file without any luck:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "~12"
  }
}
```

Update: as suggested in the comments I tried making the function async:

```js
module.exports = async function(context, myTimer) {
    const webhint = hint.Analyzer.create({}, {});
    const result = await webhint.analyze('https://google.com', {});
    context.done();
};
```

That introduces a new problem:

```
mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.WebHintFunction. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. C:\projects\webhint-function-app\WebhintFunction\WebHintFunction\index.js:3
module.exports = async function run(context, myTimer) {
                       ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: You can't have an async arrow function unless the containing function is also async.

Comment: Questions updated 